# Jenkins2 installer in macOS change home directory

Tags: jenkins, macos-sierra

I am new to Jenkins, and I have the following problem

just installed Jenkins2 on MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) 
and a new user has been created under /Users/Shared/Jenkins/,
but when I try to run a maven compile command, through a new Job
I have the following error:

```
[atmosphere] $ mvn -f spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere/pom.xml compile
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I try to run the command manually and got the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException:
 Cannot create resource output directory: 
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/atmosphere/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere/target/classes
```

How could I solve this ? 
I guess I have to change the workspace permissions, but I don't know how to do that.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

It was really a newbie mistake.

I didn't have installed the maven plugin.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906972/cannot-run-program-mvn-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory) post helped me to solve the problem.