# How can I build my maven application succesfully on Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and don't have much luck. I am trying to build my spring boot application with maven in it. It builds succesfully until I add commands "clean compile package" in Invoke top-level Maven targets.

The build fails.

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/jobs/sample/workspace
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/jobs/sample/workspace/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/rshncp/stackApp.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/rshncp/stackApp.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/rshncp/stackApp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 497d77eeef33f9cc19c5390d21cf49e90ac24e05 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 497d77eeef33f9cc19c5390d21cf49e90ac24e05 # timeout=10
Commit message: "first commit"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 497d77eeef33f9cc19c5390d21cf49e90ac24e05 # timeout=10
[workspace] $ mvn clean compile package
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/sample/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:995)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:507)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:518)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:367)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your Jenkins machine has not 'mvn' installed on it, try to install Maven first

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Maven as plug-in. You must go to Jenkins Global Tool Configuration, and configure a Maven version with automatic installer (from the web).
2. Setup in global configuration, maven version. Look second answer of this case [Cannot run program "mvn" error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906972/cannot-run-program-mvn-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory)