# Issue while building a job in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

[Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtjOU.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run program "mvn" error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906972/cannot-run-program-mvn-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: No pictures of text, especially if you can't even frame the screen properly!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this problem is to install git.

1. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available and search for “Git Plugin”
2. Install Git Plugin
3. Restart Jenkins